# "remote: Unauthorized", "fatal: Authentication failed for..." (Bitbucket)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I was following the "Clone a repository" tutorial in the README.md. I didn't have SourceTree, so I was following the instructions for "clone from the command line" (which I understood to be Git). When I got to copy the commands to clone over HTTPS/SSH, both commands wouldn't work. I've read that you needed a folder which you had authentication for and made a new one in my C: drive named "bitbucketstationslocations". When I pasted the commands to Git again it would show me this:

```
Cloning into 'bitbucketstationlocations'...
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://username@bitbucket.org/username/bit
bucketstationlocations.git/'
```

I have also unset my user.name and user.email using `git config --global --unset-all user.name` and `git config --global --unset-all user.email` because I thought it might be giving the wrong credentials.

Comment: I maybe stating the obvious here, but are you authorized to access the repo? Are you able to access it from BitBucket? Also do you use any `credential.helper` (git config -l | grep 'cred')?

Comment: It's also worth noting that `user.email` and `user.name` are only used for commits themselves - they do not, in any way whatsoever, have a single thing to do with authenticating to any remote systems.

Comment: @Anthony, how did you solved this issue?